# highchart legend symbol is not appearing, for holo column

Tags: highcharts

I wanted to show Bar(column) chart using HighChart, but bar chart should show holo columns(transparent column with borders). For this purpose I set `color` and `borderColor` as follows

```
    plotOptions: {
    series: {
        color: Highcharts.Color('#000000').setOpacity(0).get('rgba'),//'#000000'
        borderColor: '#000000'
    }
},
```

but it is not showing series symbol in legends, as shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdulQ/hfuuocdw/) jsFiddle. Is there anyway to show series symbol in Legends, keeping columns(bars) to appear holo(transparent with visible borders).

Comment: series color is `#000000`, so legend symbols not appearing

Comment: yes. this is because I set it, to make columns holo, and I already know this reason. I wanted to know, is there any way to set symbol to appear in border color of the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting color and border color of each series, and then adding a css style for "fill" to be transparent, as shown in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/AbdulQ/fsf7n1yq/) fiddle.

```
.highcharts-series-group .highcharts-point {
  fill: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using ideas from [Style by CSS](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) from highcharts to customize the label

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/prfyqLs3/)

css

```
.highcharts-legend-item * { /*for default case*/
  fill: black !important;
}

.highcharts-legend-item-hidden * { /*when clicked*/
  fill: gray !important;
}
```

Comment: still some more customization required or some errors

Answer (score 0):

The legend symbol is not showing because it's color has the opacity 0, the same as the serie.
Couldn't find anything that would allow you to set the color of the marker, but i have a workaround.
You can format the legend label with the symbol, here you can find some of those symbols http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/list.htm

Here is the code to hide the legend symbol when it's hidden and format it's label.

```
legend: {
        symbolPadding: 0,
        symbolWidth: 0.001,
        symbolHeight: 0.001,
        symbolRadius: 0,
        labelFormatter: function () {
             return "◼ " + this.name;
    }
},
```

full fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hfuuocdw/2/